# gcc : Unable to find Python.h, When its there in /usr/includes/python2.7?

Tags: python, c, gcc, include, include-path

My C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "Python.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

I have `python-dev` installed for python2.7. Moreover, `Python.h` is available in `/usr/include/python2.7`.

`gcc myfile.c` # Python.h: No such file or directory

I even tried :
`gcc -L/usr/include/python2.7/ myfile.c` # Python.h: No such file or directory

I tried building a python c module `ujson` with pip that uses `Python.h`, it was able to compile.

**What am I missing / doing wrong ?**

Comment: use -I in place of -L, better solution: write a makefile (yeah it will require some study, but the effort is worth while). Compiling on the command line can be a big pain

Comment: Even better, if this code is a Python extension: write a `setup.py` file and use distutils.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be `-I`, not `-L`:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 myfile.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
#include <Python.h>
```

instead of

```
#include "Python.h"
```

to [include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename) the header file.
The Python.h file should be the first file which is included.

@see [Extending Python with C or C++](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html) (Section 1.1 Note)

> Since Python may define some pre-processor definitions which affect
>   the standard headers on some systems, you must include Python.h before
>   any standard headers are included.